# Postgresql (pgAdmin 4) - How to change in system settings decimal separator from dots to commas

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

In Poland we use comma instead of dot as decimal separator. My whole databases use commas and I have this error when I want to import data to postgrsql:

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "0,000"
CONTEXT: COPY Sheet1, line 2, column Sales quantity: "0,000"
SQL state: 22P02

How can I change Postgresql settings so that it accepts commas instead of dots as decimal separator?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the configuration parameter `lc_numeric`. This can happen through the configuration parameter file at db startup or on-the-fly in sql (For other ways to interact with the parameters consult the respective [docs' section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/config-setting.html)).

In order to change the settigns across the whole cluster, use:

```
ALTER SYSTEM lc_numeric TO 'pl_PL.UTF-8'; -- Check the original setting first !!!
```

This might not be a good idea for a one-time job (and you likely do not have the privileges anyway).

The following steps illustrate how to switch between Anglo-American and Polish convention of number formatting for the current sql transaction:

```
-- show the current setting. let's say it is 'en_US.UTF-8'. Remember/store for later.
show lc_numeric;

-- American style.
select to_char(123456789.8765, '999G999G999D99');

-- Set to Polish convention (group separator ' ', decimal: ',') 
set lc_numeric to 'pl_PL.UTF-8';

-- Polish style
select to_char(123456789.8765, '999G999G999D99');

-- Restore original value
set lc_numeric to 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

Tested on Postgresql 12. Further details in the docs, sections [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set.html) and [Locale config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT).